# Edit Photos via Photoshop on a server

Tags: image-processing, web-applications, server, photoshop

I wart to create a web app where a user enters certain data via a form and then receives a custom rendered image. The image is from a smart object in a psd. It's kind of like a mock-up which definitely requires needs some photoshop filters to be properly rendered.

This should all happen in real time and should be doable from my understanding since the rendering of a single images doesn't need much computing power

I've done some research and haven't really found a solution the matches my problem. Is it necessary to run Photoshop on a server and then remotely run a photoshop script and then upload the generated image somewhere else?

I've used The After Effects Plugin Template by DataClay in the past which offers similar functionality but for video.

Looking forward to hearing your ideas.
Thanks

Comment: You will likely find downloading, opening and saving will take much more time than the processing itself. I would reconsider the idea of it being realtime. Depends on the scale of your application of course.

Comment: My company uses gimp headless for processing and creating psd files. Might not work with your specific features though.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Dataclay plugin to handle still image exports out of After Effects.  Make a single-frame duration composition in After Effects and rig the layers with the Templater plugin.  Then use the PNG Sequence output module to render out a single frame.

From [Dataclay's forums](https://forums.dataclay.com/topic/162/importing-and-exporting-png-sequences-using-templater?_=1619365203614):

> Exporting
>
> A few extra steps are required to correctly render a project file as a PNG sequence using Templater. By default, a file rendered as a PNG sequence will have the frame number appended to the end of the file name, i.e.:
>
> `filename.png00000`, `filename.png00001`, `filename.png00002`, etc.
>
> In order to designate where in the filename the frame number should be added, we’ll need to use the output column. First, add a column named output to your data source. Next, add a filename with a set of brackets with five # signs to designate where the frame numbering should be added. For example:

`filename[#####]` would result in `filename00001.png`

or

`[#####]filename` would result in `00001filename.png`